# Extracting values from JSON list

Tags: sql, json, database, amazon-athena, rdbms

I have sample data like below, I want to display all project names, and not just one by passing index.

By trying below sql getting only 'project1'. Need both project1 and project2 in concatination.

```
WITH dataset AS (
   SELECT '{"name": "Bob Smith",
             "org": "engineering",
             "projects": [{"name":"project1", "completed":false},{"name":"project2", "completed":true}]}'
     AS myblob
)
SELECT json_extract_scalar(myblob, '$.projects[0].name') AS project_name
FROM dataset
```

Expecting like both project1 and project2 in concatination.

```
project_name
project1,project2
```

Comment: Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should **include** code examples, table structure, sample data, **and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.)** being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try the code below
WITH dataset AS (
   SELECT '{"name": "Bob Smith",
             "org": "engineering",
             "projects": [{"name":"project1", "completed":false},{"name":"project2", "completed":true}]}'
     AS myblob
)
SELECT CONCAT(
        json_extract_scalar(myblob, '$.projects[0].name'),
        ',',
        json_extract_scalar(myblob, '$.projects[1].name')
    ) AS project_names
FROM dataset;
```

Comment: Thanks @Ugochukwu Obinna. The thing is we dont know the array lenthgh, We cant hardcode the index, It should be dynamic.

Comment: You can always create a table holding the number from 0 to 999 (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/Yj_JWAiS ) It would not be very hard to increase the maximum, when needed.